# App idea i need to copyright or patent

Tags: patentability

What is the process i can take to either patent or copyright an idea for a smartphone app? How can I present my idea to a company like google or apple?

Answer (score -1):

One example of how this could be done is [Lonnie Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonnie_Johnson_(inventor)) and his [Super Soaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Soaker) idea. In short, he created a prototype, presented it at an exhibition event, and pitched his idea to a company executive. Along the way he protected his idea with patent(s) and/or copyright(s).

Comment: Unfortunately, software is somewhat more nuanced in that it isn't as likely to be patentable as an actual physical device.

Answer (score -1):

The idea of the app need to be new and non-obvious for patent. Then you need to check it over the patent website whether that idea is already present or it is unique. If it is not there and you believe its a new invention you can file your application for patent with a nominal fee of 1600 (if it is individual) or 8000 (if it is of some organization). In your case it will be 1600.

Comment: I’m assuming you mean dollars and this is for a US patent, but it isn’t clear. Also there is the cost of a patent attorney or agent which the inventor really should employ if they want a useful patent.